# Adjust the height of a div for slider content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on a site that was built by one of our vendors (who we no longer work with).

There's a div on a page used to hold the contents of a slider.  The slider has a number of different panes, each with a photo and some text.  When you click the left or right arrows, the content slides to the right or left to show the next pane of content.  The number of panes is dynamic.

On page load, the div's height is equal to the height of it's current content.  I'm  using a jQuery plugin called [EqualHeights](http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/) which I guess the original developer thought would take the height of the tallest content pane and set it as the height of the div.

Unfortunately the plugin doesn't do what it's supposed to do - at least not in this application.  Does anyone have any idea how I could set the height of this div?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.next-or-previous-buttons').click(function () {
  $('div.content-container').height($('.content .selected').height());
});
```

Does that not work?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try a min-height using CSS?